# Changing css properties in an iframe based on parent window

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to run an iframe on two different pages on a website but with different css properties. Due to a limitation of space on my index.php, I'd like to confine text in the iframe to a small width, whereas on another page (samples/index.php), there is no limitation on width and the iframe can be bigger. If I use the same "large" width on both pages and have the iframe narrower on the index.php, the text and will go off the edge and be obscured (I don't want to use scrollbars).

In  index.php, I have the following declaration:

```
<iframe id="iframe_1" src="samples/data-iframe.html" width="850px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

In samples/index.php, the width is narrower

```
<iframe id="iframe_2" src="data-iframe.html" width="620px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

data-iframe.html declares the css as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">

#gallery { position: relative; width:500px; height:340px; margin:0; padding:0; }
#gallery li { display: block; }

p.blocktext {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 800px;
font-size:11px;
color: black;
background-color: white;
}

#everything {
border-style:double;
border-width:3px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 830px;
background-color: white;
}
#everything hr { width:600px; }

</style>
```

This encompasses everything within a div of width 830 pixels bounded by a double lined border, and the text inside confined to an area of 800px.

The actual content that is displayed by the iframe comes from an external javascript file - this is immediately below the css statements:

```
<script src="samples/test-iframe.js"></script>
```

Within test-iframe.js we have, for example:

```
document.write("<center>");
document.write("<div id=\"everything\">");
document.write("<ul id=\"gallery\">"); 
document.write("<li><img src=\"photo1.jpg\" alt=\"\" /></li>");
document.write("<li><img src=\"photo2.jpg\" alt=\"\" /></li>");
document.write("<li><img src=\"photo3.jpg\" alt=\"\" /></li>");
document.write("<li><img src=\"photo4.jpg\" alt=\"\" /></li>");
document.write("<li><img src=\"photo5.jpg\" alt=\"\" /></li>");
document.write("</ul>");
document.write("<p class=\"blocktext\">Dummy text.</p><hr><p class=\"blocktext\">More Dummy text (Note the hr to separate the two portions of text)</p></div>");
document.write("</center>");
```

All the images have been resized to be within the large iframe on index.php and the smaller one on samples/index.php
Conceivably the text could be very large - above its just a placeholder, but its confined in a smaller area.

I'm trying to use the following code to find out what the parent window is - if it contains "samples", then display the complete width of the text etc. if not - use a restricted width.

```
var str = parent.location.href;
var nt = str.indexOf("samples");

var a = document.getElementById("blocktext");
var b = document.getElementById("everything");

if (nt>0) // samples found  
{
a.style.width = "800px";
b.style.width = "830px";
b.style.hr = "600px";
}
else // samples not found - narrower confines
{
a.style.width = "500px";  
b.style.width = "600px";  
b.style.hr = "400px"; 
}
```

For some reason, this doesn't work; the css isn't being updated. I've put some test code in the if blocks and found out that the code is properly determining the parent window, but its not changing the widths or hr properties. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: Careful, none of your iframe elements has "blocktext" for ID (only class name for your last 'p' tag)... 'a' is therefore yet undefined.

Comment: Thanks, I deserve a kick for missing that. It's thrown up some other problems though which I'm trying to solve.

Comment: The first step would be to stop (mis-)using `document.write`, especially writing partial elements like that.

Comment: you should use dynamic sizes and `@media` queries.

Comment: I have to use document.write, as the iframe's content is dynamically generated using Javascript to determine content based on date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use css `@media` queries instead of javascript to make sure your content fits:

```
p.blocktext {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 800px;
font-size:11px;
color: black;
background-color: white;
}

#everything {
border-style:double;
border-width:3px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 830px;
background-color: white;
}
#everything hr { width:600px; }

@media all and (max-width: 829px) {
    p.blocktext {
        width: 500px;
    }
    #everything {
        width: 600px;
    }
    #everything hr {
       width: 400px;
    }
}
```

But it would be better practise to design with dynamic sizes.

Comment: Thank you, this looks intriguing. I have done some reading and was curious if "all" refers to the parent window or the iframe window. If its the iframe window, I can specify the different widths in the different pages and the @media should hopefully pick it up and change the css attributes accordingly?

Comment: @user3713442 `all` is not important it just means that this while apply to any media. But the `min-width` is and it means that the parent window(in this case the iframesize) must be larger than specified for the styles to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried it and it didn't work at first - but then I changed "min-width" to "max-width" and it works fine now. It seems like a very powerful utility this, I just wish the manuals were clearer and says this applies to the parent window, regardless of whether its the iframe or the main window.

Comment: I am glad i helped, `@media` queries can be confusing and here is a good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries